# The portgroup for Network adapter 1, could not be found

Tags: vmware-esxi, redhat, kvm-virtualization, vmware-vcenter, rhel7

I am trying to run RHCSA Lab on MY VMWare Exsi 6.5. after copied my VM file and I have a warning on VMware Exsi "The portgroup for Network adapter 1, , could not be found.It has been assigned to **MYPORT** port group". Any Idea ?

Answer (score 0):

The VM has a port group specified in the VM file that doesn't exist, so vSphere was kind enough to assign it to the default port group on the vSwitch. This is common if you copy complete VMs between environments instead of deploying a new VM from a template for example.